# Application crash when taking image with camera in cordova 2.7.0 with android 4.1.1

Tags: android, cordova, camera

I have a problem when i take an image in my android application, after i press the check button, the application crashes,

This is what i get, in my logcat

```
9 10:33:51.422: E/Trace(27079): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   resume activity {com.infobia.robocompta/com.infobia.robocompta.MyPhoneGapActivity}:   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=33,   result=-1, data=null} to activity   {com.infobia.robocompta/com.infobia.robocompta.MyPhoneGapActivity}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079):    at   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2216)
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=33, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.infobia.robocompta/com.infobia.robocompta.MyPhoneGapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3302)
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2715)
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079):    ... 12 more
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079):    at org.apache.cordova.DroidGap.onActivityResult(DroidGap.java:850)
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5204)
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3298)
08-09 10:33:51.717: E/AndroidRuntime(27079):    ... 13 more
```

and this is the camera code

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
 var myData ="";
 function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData)
 {

// alert('onPhotoDataSuccess');
var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

// Unhide image elements

smallImage.style.display = 'block';

// Show the captured photo
// The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
 smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
 myData = imageData;
 }

function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI)
{


// Get image handle
//
var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

// Unhide image elements
//
largeImage.style.display = 'block';

// Show the captured photo
// The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
largeImage.src = imageURI;
}



function capturePhoto()
{
// Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
//alert('capturePhoto');
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI, correctOrientation: true });

}



function capturePhotoEdit()
{

 navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI });
}


function getPhoto(source)
{
// Retrieve image file location from specified source
 navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,destinationType:  destinationType.FILE_URI,sourceType: source });
}


function onFail(message)
{
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

I tried the foureground plugin but the client didn't appreciate it, also to uncheck Do not keep actitivies.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you find the solution for it?